# boundary problem

Tags: differential-equations

I have some conditions at `t=0`, like `r1^2+r2^2=0.5` and `x^2+y^2=6` and I want to find the right initial values in the past like `t=-20`, which reproduces this conditions. For example I have this system here.

```
alpha = 0.5
beta = 1

sol = NDSolve[{

x'[t] == -x[t]*a[t] - 3*x[t] + alpha*y[t]^2 + 
  1/2*beta*(r1[t]^2 - r2[t]^2),
y'[t] == -y[t]*a[t] - alpha*x[t]*y[t], 
r1'[t] == -r1[t]*a[t] - 3/2*r1[t] + beta*x[t]*r1[t], 
r2'[t] == -r2[t]*a[t] - 3/2*r2[t] - beta*x[t]*r2[t],
z'[t] == -z[t]*a[t] - 2*z[t],
x[-20] == 0, y[-20] == 10^(-12), r1[-20] == 0.008, 
r2[-20] == 0.008, z[-20] == 0.999},
{x, y, r1, r2, z},
{t, 0, -20}];
a[t_] = -1/2*(3 - 3*y[t]^2 + 3*x[t]^2 + z[t]^2)
```

In c++ I would build something with a `While` loop. But in *Mathematica* I don't know and the documentation of *Mathematica* doesn't help me.

Comment: Does anyone know something about boundary value problems?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it effectively. But you should define `a[t_]` before using it.

Comment: There will almost certainly be multiple solutions corresponding to various combinations of `{x[-20],y[-20],z[-20],r1[-20],r2[-20]}`. If you have an idea of the range of these functions, or if you have other boundary conditions, the easiest way would be to include your criteria as conditions as well, i.e.:`r1[0]^2+r2[0]^2==0.5`

Answer (score 1):

First let us find all the solution as functions (I'm going to use `ReplaceAll(\.)` for that).

```
Clear[a,x, y, z, r1, r2]

alpha = 0.5;
beta = 1;

tmin = -20; tmax = 0;

a[t_] = -1/2*(3 - 3*y[t]^2 + 3*x[t]^2 + z[t]^2);

{{x, y, r1, r2, z}} = {x, y, r1, r2, z} /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]*a[t] - 3*x[t] + alpha*y[t]^2 + 1/2*beta*(r1[t]^2 - r2[t]^2), 
 y'[t] == -y[t]*a[t] - alpha*x[t]*y[t], 
 r1'[t] == -r1[t]*a[t] - 3/2*r1[t] + beta*x[t]*r1[t], 
 r2'[t] == -r2[t]*a[t] - 3/2*r2[t] - beta*x[t]*r2[t], 
 z'[t] == -z[t]*a[t] - 2*z[t], x[-20] == 0, y[-20] == 10^(-12), 
 r1[-20] == 0.008, r2[-20] == 0.008, z[-20] == 0.999}, {x, y, r1, 
 r2, z}, {t, tmin,tmax}];
```

If you wish you can check your solutions by,

```
Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t], r1[t], r2[t]}, {t,tmin,tmax}]
```

Now you want to make good guess for initial value and I think you want to do it iteratively (as you mention `While`). I am not sure what is convergence criterion, so I'll give you a general example. Say your initial values are `m` and `n` and your convergence  condition is  `q = m+n < 5.65`. Now you can use `While` (yes it is there in *Mathematica* as well)

```
m = 1; n = 1; (*initial guess*)
While[q = m + n; q < 5.65, Print[m, "  ", n, "  ", q]; m = m + 0.2; n = n + 0.3]
```

But I rather suggest you to use a `Do` loop.

```
Do[q = m + n; If[q > 5.5 && q < 5.65, Print[m, "  ", n, "  ", q]], {m, 1.3,4.1, .23}, {n, 1.7, 4.2, .21}]
```

Now you can scan the convergence within a particular range of initial values. Here I narrow down the condition just to show you that you can do it. You can use additional `Break[]` to stop the loop soon as you find your first set of initial values.

Say you convergence criterion is `0<x^2+y^2<0.001` at `t=0`. Then the structure will be like

```
Do[  Clear[a,x,y, ...
...
.
... x[-20]==xini, y[-20]==yini, ...

conv[t_]:=x[t]^2+y[t]^2;
If[conv[0] > 0.0 && conv[0] < 0.001, initval={xini,yini, ...}; Break[]];

,{xini,xini1,xini2,dxini}, {yini,yini1,yini2,dyini}, ...]
```

`initval` will record your answer. You can make a clever guess for a range of initial values and play with it whole day.